# Force GCC to keep section when using link time optimization

Tags: gcc, sections, lto

I have a C `struct` that is compiled by GCC into a special section and placed at the beginning of an output binary via a linker script.  It contains file metadata, including a magic value at the beginning.

Here's a simplified example using just a string as the struct.

```c
const char __magic_value[9] __attribute__((section(".the_header"))) = "MAGICVAL";
```

GCC places this value into its own section, as we can see with `readelf -S`:

```
There are 10 section headers, starting at offset 0x190:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000000 00  AX  0   0  2
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 3] .bss              NOBITS          00000000 000034 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 4] .the_header       PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000009 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 5] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 00003d 00001e 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 6] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 00005b 000033 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00008e 000051 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0000e0 000090 10      9   8  4
  [ 9] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000170 00001e 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

(Note section #4.)

Now, if I specify `-flto` to the GCC invocation, this section is no longer emitted!

```
There are 19 section headers, starting at offset 0x730:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000000 00  AX  0   0  2
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 3] .bss              NOBITS          00000000 000034 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 4] .gnu.lto_.profile PROGBITS        00000000 000034 00000f 00   E  0   0  1
  [ 5] .gnu.lto_.icf.93e PROGBITS        00000000 000043 000017 00   E  0   0  1
  [ 6] .gnu.lto_.jmpfunc PROGBITS        00000000 00005a 00000f 00   E  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.lto_.inline. PROGBITS        00000000 000069 00000f 00   E  0   0  1
  [ 8] .gnu.lto_.purecon PROGBITS        00000000 000078 00000f 00   E  0   0  1
  [ 9] .gnu.lto_.symbol_ PROGBITS        00000000 000087 000022 00   E  0   0  1
  [10] .gnu.lto_.refs.93 PROGBITS        00000000 0000a9 00000f 00   E  0   0  1
  [11] .gnu.lto_.decls.9 PROGBITS        00000000 0000b8 000239 00   E  0   0  1
  [12] .gnu.lto_.symtab. PROGBITS        00000000 0002f1 00001d 00   E  0   0  1
  [13] .gnu.lto_.opts    PROGBITS        00000000 00030e 0000e8 00   E  0   0  1
  [14] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 0003f6 00001e 01  MS  0   0  1
  [15] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 000414 000033 00      0   0  1
  [16] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000447 00018c 00      0   0  1
  [17] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0005d4 000130 10     18  17  4
  [18] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000704 00002c 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

My linker script does not find the `.the_header` section, resulting in a corrupt binary.

I have tried specifying `__attribute__((used))` for the header variable, with no effect.

Here's the relevant part of the linker script:

```
ENTRY(main)

MEMORY
{
  APP (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 65536
}

SECTIONS
{
    .header :
    {
        KEEP(*(.the_header))

    } > APP

    ...
}
```

How do I tell GCC to emit `.the_header` into the final binary when using link time optimization and the above linker script snippet?

Comment: Report a bug to gcc? Actually, it works for me, I do get a section .the_header in the final binary even with LTO... (I don't get one in the .o file obviously)

Comment: Or I can get the section in the .o file with `-ffat-lto-objects`, but that kind of defeats the point of LTO.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, `-ffat-lto-objects` does emit a `.the_header` section.  Perhaps this has to do with the linker script...  I've added the relevant bits.  Would anything there have to do with the failure to emit the section, even with fat objects?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2015-03/msg00094.html https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1418073 Looks like you will have to compile that part of your program without LTO...

Comment: Ugh, that's unfortunate.  Thanks for the link.  If you want to convert it to an answer, I'll mark it as accepted!